# Change Scroll Bar Height After Clicking a Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm coding a website and I want to change the height of the scroll bar in JavaScript after clicking a button:

```js
var scrollHeight = document.getElementById("height");
scrollHeight.scrollHeight = 50;
```

`"height"` is the `id` of the body. Was that wrong?

Comment: Element.scrollHeight read-only property

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Comment: @RandomCoder You want to change height or scroll to specific position?

Comment: Hi, I'm not clear what you are trying to do - scrollHeight refers to the height an element would need so it wouldn't have to be scrolled to see it all. Could you explain more what you are trying to style?

Comment: I'm creating a website with a dropdown and when someone selects something it goes to info. about it.

Comment: @TechySharnav I want to change the height

Comment: @RandomCoder try `scrollHeight.style.height = "50px"`